# Depth first search implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, graph, depth-first-search

I've been practicing my algorithms using [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849967202). I've decided to implement the depth first search section (5.8) using javascript. Note you can execute the code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php) if you don't have node.js.

```
var doDFS = function(graph, source, directed, processVertexEarly, processVertexLate, processEdge, logOff) {
    var finished = false;
    var time = 0;
    var discovered = [];
    var processed = [];
    var entry_time = [];
    var exit_time = [];
    var parent = [];

    if (!logOff) console.log();
    if (!logOff) console.log('*****************************');
    if (!logOff) console.log('DFS starting at', source, 'for adjacency list:');
    if (!logOff) console.log(graph);

    (function recDoDFS(u) {
        if (finished) return;
        discovered[u] = true;
        if (!logOff) console.log('DISCOVERED', u);
        time = ++time;
        entry_time[u] = time;

        processVertexEarly(u);

        var adjList = graph[u];
        for (var i = 0; i < adjList.length; i++) {
            v = adjList[i];
            if (!discovered[v]) {
                parent[v] = u;
                recDoDFS(v);
            } else if (!processed[v] || directed) {
                processEdge(u, v);

                if (finished) return;
            }
        }
        processVertexLate(u);

        time = ++time;
        exit_time[u] = time;

        processed[u] = true;
    })(source);

    if (!logOff) console.log();
    if (!logOff) console.log('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DFS Info %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%');
    for (var i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        if (!logOff) console.log();
        if (!logOff) console.log('NODE', i);
        if (!logOff) console.log('discovered:', discovered[i]);
        if (!logOff) console.log('processed:', processed[i]);
        if (!logOff) console.log('parent:', parent[i]);
        if (!logOff) console.log('entry time:', entry_time[i]);
        if (!logOff) console.log('exit time:', exit_time[i]);
        if (!logOff) console.log();
    }
    if (!logOff) console.log('############ DFS OVER ############');
    if (!logOff) console.log();
};

var PVE = function(v, logOff) {
    if (!logOff) console.log('Early processed vertex:', v);
};

var PVL = function(v, logOff) {
    if (!logOff) console.log('Late processed vertex:', v);
};

var PE = function(u, v, logOff) {
    if (!logOff) console.log('Processed edge:', '(' + u + ', ' + v + ')');
};

var adjList = [
    [1],
    [0, 4, 5],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [2, 6],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 6],
    [3, 5],
    [8],
    [],
    []
];

doDFS(adjList, 0, false, PVE, PVL, PE);
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, looks like you've posted 8 questions but only selected an answer on one of them.  Consider accepting the most helpful answer on your previous posts before posting new questions.

Comment: Good point. Will do